# Insertion into database

Tags: mysql, insert

I have to write into MySQL database a lot of data for about 5 times per second.
What is the fastest way: insert each 1/5 of second or make a queue and insert all stored data each ~5 seconds? If the second way is better - is it possible to insert into 1 table using 1 request a few rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the frequency of the insertions 
Its **better** to go with the second approach that is queuing and than adding at one go.!

But You should consider these scenarios first :

1. Is your system Real Time.? Yes then what is the maximum delay that you can afford (As it'll take ~5 seconds for next insertion and data to be persisted/available)?
2. What are the chances of Incorrect values/Errors to come in data, as if one data is incorrect you'll loose rest all if the query has to fail.

Comment: Yeah, the system is real time. The data is a simple base64 with ~100 bytes of data.

Comment: If so I would go with single insertion, and with Connection Pooling at DAO layer. Because you can not afford to loose data in RTS as well the time is also critical.! Hope this helped you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple buffer pools with `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`. it can depend on number of cores onmachine. 
Use `Partitioning` of table.
You can collectively insert data using `XML`.

Answer (score 2):

As each transaction comes with a fixed cost, I'd say that doing a multi-line insert every few seconds is better. With some of the systems we use at work we cache hundreds of lines before inserting them all in one go.

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) you can do a multi-line insert like so:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make an insert with all the data witho something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (field1, field2,... , fieldN )
VALUES 
(value1_1', value1_2,... , value1_N),
(value2_1', value2_2,... , value2_N),
...
(valueM_1', valueM_2,... , valueM_N);
```

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that when inserting data into a MySQL database it is faster to work with batches.

So the **slower** option is executing multiple insert queries:

```
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, "a");
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (2, "b");
```

The **faster** option would be:

```
    INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, "a"), (2, "b");
```